# Explode date interval over a group by and take last value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe which contains some products, a date and a value. Now the dates have different gaps inbetween recorded values that I want to fill out. Such that I have a recorded value for every hour from the first time the product was seen to the last, if there is no record I want to use the latest value.

So, I have a dataframe like:

```
| ProductId | Date                          | Value |
|-----------|-------------------------------|-------|
| 1         | 2020-03-12T00:00:00.000+0000  | 4     |
| 1         | 2020-03-12T01:00:00.000+0000  | 2     |
| 2         | 2020-03-12T01:00:00.000+0000  | 3     |
| 2         | 2020-03-12T03:00:00.000+0000  | 4     |
| 1         | 2020-03-12T05:00:00.000+0000  | 4     |
| 3         | 2020-03-12T05:00:00.000+0000  | 2     |
```

I want to create a new dataframe that looks like:

```
| ProductId | Date                          | Value |
|-----------|-------------------------------|-------|
| 1         | 2020-03-12T00:00:00.000+0000  | 4     |
| 1         | 2020-03-12T01:00:00.000+0000  | 2     |
| 1         | 2020-03-12T02:00:00.000+0000  | 2     |
| 1         | 2020-03-12T03:00:00.000+0000  | 2     |
| 1         | 2020-03-12T04:00:00.000+0000  | 2     |
| 1         | 2020-03-12T05:00:00.000+0000  | 4     |
| 2         | 2020-03-12T01:00:00.000+0000  | 3     |
| 2         | 2020-03-12T02:00:00.000+0000  | 3     |
| 2         | 2020-03-12T03:00:00.000+0000  | 4     |
| 3         | 2020-03-12T05:00:00.000+0000  | 2     |
```

My code so far:

```
def generate_date_series(start, stop):
  start = datetime.strptime(start, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
  stop = datetime.strptime(stop, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
  return [start + datetime.timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(0, (stop-start).hours + 1)]

spark.udf.register("generate_date_series", generate_date_series, ArrayType(TimestampType()))

df = df.withColumn("max", max(col("Date")).over(Window.partitionBy("ProductId"))) \
       .withColumn("min", min(col("Date")).over(Window.partitionBy("ProductId"))) \
       .withColumn("Dato", explode(generate_date_series(col("min"), col("max"))) \
                          .over(Window.partitionBy("ProductId").orderBy(col("Dato").desc())))

window_over_ids = (Window.partitionBy("ProductId").rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1).orderBy("Date"))

df = df.withColumn("Value", last("Value", ignorenulls=True).over(window_over_ids))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Column
```

So the first question is obviously how do I create and call the udf correctly so I don't run into the above error.

The second question is how do I complete the task, such that I get my desired dataframe?

Comment: Looking at [these examples](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.UDFRegistration.register), I think you should not be passing `col("min")` as an argument to your UDF, you should pass just the column name `"min"`.

Comment: I believe that is only when you execute through spark.sql.

Comment: Hum, actually the problem is that `spark.udf.register` returns the callable object that should be used in the query instead of `generate_date_series`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some searching and experimenting I found a solution. I defined a udf that returns a date range between two dates with 1 hour intervals. And I then do a forward fill

I fixed the issue with the following code:

```
def missing_hours(t1, t2):
    return [t1 + timedelta(hours=x) for x in range(0, int((t2-t1).total_seconds()/3600))]

missing_hours_udf = udf(missing_hours, ArrayType(TimestampType()))

window = Window.partitionBy("ProductId").orderBy("Date")

df_missing = df.withColumn("prev_timestamp", lag(col("Date"), 1, None).over(window)) \
                        .filter(col("prev_timestamp").isNotNull()) \
                        .withColumn("Date", explode(missing_hours_udf(col("prev_timestamp"), col("Date")))) \
                        .withColumn("Value", lit(None)) \
                        .drop("prev_timestamp")

df = df_original.union(df_missing)

window = Window.partitionBy("ProductId").orderBy("Date") \
               .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)

# define the forward-filled column
filled_values_column = last(df['Value'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)

# do the fill
df = df.withColumn('Value', filled_values_column)
```